# Redirect to same page after form submitted in views.py not working while using Django paginator

Tags: javascript, python, django, fetch-api

I want to redirect to same page after submitting form which fetches view from views.py. The problem is paginator. After submitting Django form page reloads to page 1. I want browser to stay on the same page after submitting form. Error I get: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'http' is not a registered namespace. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Code calling path in js:

```
let path = window.location.href
```

Fetching api:

```
            subedit[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch(`/edit/${content[i].id}`,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                mode: 'same-origin',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                post: textarea[i].value,
                page: path           
                })}).then(() => {
                    editdiv[i].style.display = 'none';
                    post[i].style.display = 'block';
                })})
```

views.py:

```
def edit(request, post_id):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    content = data.get("post", "")
    post=Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    page = data.get("page", "")
    if request.method == "POST":
        if post.user == request.user:
            post.post=content
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(page)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using sessions:

```
<a id="page" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a>
```

```
let page=document.querySelector("#page").innerHTML
            fetch(`/edit/${content[i].id}`,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                mode: 'same-origin',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                post: textarea[i].value,
                page: page             
                })}).then(() => {
                    editdiv[i].style.display = 'none';
                    post[i].style.display = 'block';
                })})
```

```
def edit(request, post_id):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    content = data.get("post", "")
    post=Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    page = data.get("page", "")
    request.session['page'] = page
    if request.method == "POST":
        if post.user == request.user:
            post.post=content
            post.save()
            return HttpResponse(page)
```

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    paginator = Paginator(posts,10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    if request.session.has_key('page'):
        page_number = request.session['page']
        del request.session['page']
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`reverse(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) looks for a view with the given *name*, it does not take a URL as input. You can use this directly in the [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect), so:

```
def edit(request, post_id):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    content = data.get("post", "")
    post=Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    page = data.get("page", "")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if post.user == request.user:
            post.post=content
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(page)
```

You should also return `HttpResponse`s for the GET requests, and in case the `post.user` is not the same as the `request.user`.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Hmm, I did as you said and I get error:  Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 55265). Also still the same problem. What could the problem be? Maybe because of paginator conditions in template? Should I post that code as well?

Comment: @Leon_idas: this has nothing to do with a paginator, but likely with the some database configuration, especially since this view does not paginate anything at all.

Comment: I had indented code return HttpResponseRedirect(page) one level above the code I provided. I undid this and it does not give me Broken pipe error anymore but the same problem persists

Comment: @Leon_idas: then likely the problem is located at the view where you redirect to...